# Animate UITextField textRect changes?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiviewanimation

I have a subclass of `UITextField` that based on if it's editing or not the textRect and editRect changes.

I was wondering if there is a way of animating this change. Since they are called in the background I have no idea how to trigger an animation.

```
override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let topLeft = CGPoint(paddingH+(self.editing ? 0 : imageView.frame.width), paddingV)
    let size = CGSize(bounds.width-imageView.frame.width-paddingH*2, bounds.height-paddingV*2)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: topLeft, size: size)
    return rect
}

override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return textRectForBounds(bounds)
}
```